# Is there any way i restore database to last stable stage without having Back up file?

Tags: database, sql-server-2000, backup, restore

I have a software and at instruction I ordered Operators to backup software data(SQLServer2000 locally) regularly .

But the operator didn't and by curious she restored database by the First backup (7 months earlier) . Now we have lost all software data ( database) . such a disaster .

For more information software use this query for backing up :

```
BackUP DATABASE databaseName to DISK=...
```

and this one for restoring :

```
RESTORE DATABASE databaseName FROM DISK=...
```

I appreciate any idea

Answer (score 1):

You need a complete backup file to rollback your changes. If you do not have it you can not revert back.

Does noone have a more recent backup? (localy placed somewhere on a server)
Is there any other wy to retrieve the data (maybe developement code from repositories on local computers)?

If not then you learn how important regulary backups are - NOW. Sorry.

**EDIT:**  Check [this recovering info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966495.aspx) for the possibility of recovering any of your data.

Comment: How about operation system recoveries ?